# question sql phoenix : for each different value of column A, get first result of column B?

Tags: sql, apache-phoenix

Hello I'm learning SQL recently and I'm struggled with this pb for hours:
for each different value of column A, I want to get first result of column B 
did someone know how to do this?

Here's an example

| person | account | profile_pic |
| --- | --- | --- |
| snoopy | snoppy_main | path/snoopy/000001 |
| snoopy | snoppy_twitter | path/snoopy/000003 |
| snoopy | snoppy_twitter | path/snoopy/000004 |
| snoopy | snoppy_twitter | path/snoopy/000005 |
| mickey | mickey_insta | path/mickey/001007 |
| mickey | mickey_insta | path/mickey/001008 |
| teddy | teddy_global | path/teddy/002009 |

and here's the result I want to have

| person | account | profile_pic |
| --- | --- | --- |
| snoopy | snoppy_main | path/snoopy/000001 |
| snoopy | snoppy_twitter | path/snoopy/000003 |
| mickey | mickey_insta | path/mickey/001007 |
| teddy | teddy_global | path/teddy/002009 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the `MIN` function to achieve your desired results. Eg

```sql
SELECT
    person,
    account,
    MIN(profile_pic) as profile_pic
FROM
   your_table
GROUP BY
   person,
   account
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: oh yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for! thank you very much!